# Watson Bucket in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, error-handling

A bit of background: Watson is a Microsoft customer feedback technology. When a crash, hang or other tracked failure event occurs, Watson program is activated and the dialog appears, where you can then "Search for a solution online" or just simply close it.

As most of you already know, something like this comes up in ULS logs a lot:

> w3wp.exe (0x1D38) 0x0DD4 SharePoint Server Unified Logging Service
>   c91s Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010,
>   ULSException14

So here are the questions:

1. Was that implemented on purpose in SharePoint or does it come from ASP.NET? If it's there on purpose, I can't imagine that the 9 buckets provide any sufficient information for testing purposes.
2. Since all the processes run in the background and there are no "crash" dialogs, does that mean that Watson data is sent to Microsoft automatically if the farm is connected to the internet? If yes, is there a way to configure this?